# CSV writer prints extra quotes

Tags: python

I am learning Python script. I want to read a TSV file and print the result in a particular format like below,

Input file [tab separated]:

```
1   john   henry   1.234
```

Output:

```
1,
"john",
"henry",
1.234
```

I wrote the below code.

```
tsvfile = csv.reader(open('input.tsv' , 'r'), delimiter='\t')
outfile = csv.writer(open('output.txt' , 'w+'), escapechar='\"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

row_number = 1
for row in tsvfile:
  outfile.writerow([row[0]+","])    
  outfile.writerow(['"'+row[1]+'"'+","])
  outfile.writerow(['"'+row[2]+'"'+","])
  outfile.writerow([row[3]])
  row_number = row_number + 1
```

It generates the output as

```
1,
""john""",
""henry""",
1.234
```

The script prints `",` instead of `,` and `""` instead of `"`. I am trying to understand this behavior.

Can anyone help me why my scripts prints extra " everywhere? How should I generate the expected output?

Comment: (Are you on Windows or Linux/MacOS? Python 2 or 3? which subversion?)

Comment: Just don't write out explicit quotes: `outfile.writerow([row[1]+","])`

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.10

Comment: I was using the escape char which was causing the issue as " and , need an escape char in front of it. Actially what I need can be done in a much simpler way with basic print. That worked. Thank you all for clarifying my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The script prints `",` instead of `,` and `""` instead of `"`

Yes, it's doing that because **you told it to** by specifying `escapechar='\"'` and including actual quotes and commas in your data row elements.

Commas and quotes have special meaning in CSV files.  Commas indicate where one column ends and the next column begins, like so:

```
col1, col2, col3
```

Quotes indicate that seemingly separate values are in fact to be taken together as a single unit:

```
"all these words are the first column", "and all these words are the second column"
```

However, what if your actual data contains quotes or commas?  That's where **escape characters** come in: it's a way of telling the parser "Hey, I know the next upcoming character has special meaning, but just this once I'd like you to treat it as a plain character."

A backslash is often used as the escape character.  Consider this row of exclamations:

```
ugh, cripes, gee, wow, gosh, oh\,no
```

The backslash in `oh\,no` indicates that the actual column value is `oh,no` and the embedded comma does not have its usual meaning of a column separator.

So, when you specified `escapechar='\"'` in your output writer, you told the parser "If my actual data contains commas, quote, or any other special character, I want to you to precede it with a double quote, so it is escaped."

Then, when you say `outfile.writerow(['"'+row[1]+'"'+","])`, you're telling it to write a data value that contains actual commas and quotes, so it dutifully precedes each special character with a double quote.

TL;DR -- if your data is comma-separated, you don't need to write the commas yourself.  The csv module will do it for you.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe do this, i just read the CSV file and then got trough each line and then split it and then join it with `',\n'` (and don't forget to use `repr`):

```
with open('filname.csv','r') as f, open('outfilename.txt','w') as f2:
   l=[',\n'.join(repr(x) for x in i.split()) for i in f]
   f2.write('\n'.join(l))
```

If no need cotes, do:

```
with open('filname.csv','r') as f, open('outfilename.txt','w') as f2:
   l=[',\n'.join(i.split()) for i in f]
   f2.write('\n'.join(l))
```

Comment: This does not explain the behaviour of their code. It does not help anyone learn.

Comment: @Tomalak Yeah, i didn't post something with csv module because i am not familiar with it

Comment: @McGuile Edited mine

Comment: The above code writes the single quote for all values in the input file, I would like to have quotes only for the specific string in the input like 'John' or 'henry' and no quotes for the number values. Is there any way I can avoid that?

Comment: @Anit Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

writerow([row.strip()]) will strip extra quotes

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).